# Certain selected files are not deleting when I use Disk Cleanup

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7 and have been trying to retrieve disk space, but when I run Disk Cleanup the Temporary Internet files (18.1KB) and System archived Windows Error Report (267KB) will not delete. It goes through the process as if they are being deleted, but my disk space remains the same; I then go back to Disk Cleanup to see if they have been removed and they are still there. I have tried removing them individually as well, but the outcome is still the same.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening and what I can do to get them to delete properly?

Comment: Vote to migrate to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact procedure Microsoft uses to erase those files. But if there is just 18.1k or 276k left. That look like file system overhead. Even an empty directory has a certain size on the filesystem.

I guess the remmove process just leaves a file structure which is ok.

I don't think that removing about 300k will help you anyways. You might want to